# Mismatched Managed metadata in taxonomy-hidden-list (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, term-store, taxonomy, term-set

I am having a weird issue where the taxonomy hidden list contains value which is mismatched.

A Managed metadata is getting value of different term from different term set. It is pointing at the correct term set but the term is incorrect. It doesn't belong to that term-set so, I am not sure why it is doing that. I have tried to delete the row from taxonomy hidden list. This removed the value from folder but when I create a new folder, it adds the value back and I can see the row added back in taxonomy hidden list. I am not sure what is going on. Has anyone faced this problem before and what would be the solution to this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange situation in SharePoint Online. Maybe the MMD service which updates this list was not working normally in the backend. I would suggest raising a support ticket with Microsoft as we have no control of such service in the backend.